# Runtime execution (JAR) cannot locate Java CLASSPATH and Connector J

Tags: java, jar, classpath, connector

before now, my application has always compiled and executed.  I just do my compilation using

**jar cvmf mainClass.txt starcoder.jar *.class images/*.gif images/*.jpg *.bat**

I have a

**Windows 7 OS,
Java JDK jdk1.7.0_05,
JRE JRE7,
Connector J mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin,
Using a TextPad for development,

The runtime is on C:/Program Files/Java and Java_home**

This application from TextPad, it runs well with the CLASSPATH and executes fine.
The system compiles properly but my JAR file fails to execute

**PROBLEM**:  It fails to find my CLASSPATH on runtine execution(which works perfectly on compile time) giving me this Error

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin>java -jar starcoder.jar
>   ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver SQLException: No
>   suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/starinv?user=r oot
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/mail/MessagingE xception
>           at serialz.(serialz.java:96)
>           at serialz.main(serialz.java:240) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinCla
>   ssLoader.java:583)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(C
>   lassLoaders.java:178)
>           at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>           ... 2 more

The CLASSPATH

> .;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\comm.jar;.;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar;.;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\jxl.jar;.;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\mailapi.jar;.;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\mail.jar;.;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\activation.jar;.;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jre7\lib

My connector J file is in the right location but I get an error while executing my JAR file.

I need help to resolve this.
is the same for both my development and runtime environment.

Comment: Have you tried adding the jars you need to your java call with the -cp switch?

Comment: Please give me an example.

Comment: just made answer containing example

Answer (score 0):

Try calling like this:

```
java -cp .;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\comm.jar";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\jxl.jar";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\mailapi.jar";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\mail.jar";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\activation.jar";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib" -jar starcoder.jar
```

Note that I removed your classpath's redundant "." entries and quoted each path.